# Sencha touch 2 facebook login

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I was trying to integrate facebook login feature in my sencha touch 2 application and I found the instructions on debvelopers.facebook.com. I was able to integrate the feature using that but the login window opens as a popup. Is there a way to make that login window open in the same tab and not as a popup.

here is my code for index.html

```
   <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
   <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        console.log("FB.init")

      FB.init({
        appId      : '***************', // App ID
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      });

      (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
      }(document));
     }
   </script>
```

this is the part of the code I used in aap.js which I got from debvelopers.facebook.com

```
   FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
        // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
          // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
          // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
          // have logged in to the app.

        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
          // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app, so we call
          // FB.login() to prompt them to do so. 
          // In real-life usage, you wouldn't want to immediately prompt someone to login 
          // like this, for two reasons:
          // (1) JavaScript created popup windows are blocked by most browsers unless they 
          // result from direct interaction from people using the app (such as a mouse click)
          // (2) it is a bad experience to be continually prompted to login upon page load.


        } else {
          // In this case, the person is not logged into Facebook, so we call the login() 
          // function to prompt them to do so. Note that at this stage there is no indication
          // of whether they are logged into the app. If they aren't then they'll see the Login
          // dialog right after they log in to Facebook. 
          // The same caveats as above apply to the FB.login() call here.

        }
      });
```

Comment: Have you looked through the Jog With Friends app in the examples folder of the Sencha Touch 2 source? This application is integrated with FaceBook. Also, you can check out FastBook which is an incomplete ST2 mock of the FaceBook mobile app.